# How to load content into html elements according to style-sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having two style-sheets which can be loaded each by the user choice. My style-sheets are: one.css, two.css. What I want is: If the user change the theme I want the content to be changed too.
What I did is:

```
function strcmp ( str1, str2 ) {
    return ( ( str1 == str2 ) ? 0 : ( ( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ; 
}

(function(){

          var href = $('link').attr('href');
          console.log(href); // check what style-sheet

           if(strcmp(href,'one')==0)

             $("#p1").html('this is the content for one.css');  
             $("#p1").append("still for one.css"); 

           else if(strcmp(href,'two')==0)
             $("#p1").html('this is the content for two.css');  
             $("#p1").append("still for two.css");     

          })();
```

My method is not working, any ideas?

Comment: the href must be "one.css" and not just "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the href must be "one.css" and not just "one"

try this:

```
if(strcmp(href,'one.css')==0)
```

Comment: i found the problem it was something wrong in my html document.